Proxy specific windows within same application on MacOS
Trying to proxy a specific window of an application, having multiple windows open of the same application.
An example for clarification:
Google Chrome
 - Non-proxy window
 - Window using proxy #1
 - Window using proxy #2

I've tried Proxifier, but this seems to only be able to proxy a specific application, not a specific window of an application.

In general this is not possible.
In order to use a proxy the application needs to be told which proxy to use. That means that A) the application must support proxy use and B) if you need different proxies for sub-modules/parts of the program the application must allow you to configure the proxy for those separately.
Chrome obviously falls in category A, but not in B. (Very few programs support this actually. I have never seen or even heard of one.)
Best you can do (not just for Chrome, but also applies to other browsers) is to run multiple copies of the program, each with a different user-profile. The proxy config should be specific to the user-profile so you can have multiple in parallel as long as each uses its own user-profile.
